# IE 9, 8 and 7 jquery custom light box does not appear

Tags: jquery, forms, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7

I created a custom light box that will appear with two buttons, the user must click one and then it will submit my form. Here is my code

```
function lightboxRefferal(){
          //$('body').append('<div class="lightbox" id="lightboxBg"></div>');
                $('#lightboxBg').height($('body').height());
                $('.lightbox').show();
                $('#lightboxContent').show();
                $('#lightboxContent').css("position", "absolute");
                $('#lightboxContent').css("top", Math.max(0, (($(window).height() - $('#lightboxContent').outerHeight()) / 2) + $(window).scrollTop()) + "px");
                $('#lightboxContent').css("left", Math.max(0, (($(window).width() - $('#lightboxContent').outerWidth()) / 4) + $(window).scrollLeft()) + "px");
                $('#referral_dropdown').change(function(){
                        if($(this).val() == 'Friend'){
                                $('.referral_friend').show();
                        }       else{
                                $('.referral_friend').hide();
                        }
                });
        $('#lightboxSkip').click(function(){
                $('#lightboxContent').hide();
                $('.lightbox').hide();
                $('#customers_referral').val('nodata');
                $('form[name=create_account]').submit();
        });
        $('#lightboxContinue').click(function(){
                $('#lightboxContent').hide();
                $('.lightbox').hide();
                if($('#referral_dropdown').val() == 'Friend'){
                        $('#customers_referral').val($('#referral_friend_dropdown').val());
                }else{
                        $('#customers_referral').val($('#referral_dropdown').val());
                }
                $('form[name=create_account]').submit();
        });

}
```

In all browser this works perfectly, the lightbox appears, the user clicks a button and a form is submitted, the problem is in IE 9, 8 and 7 the lightbox does not appear and submits the form anyways. What is wrong with my code? If I remove the `.submit();` the lightbox appears. Here is my HTML

```
<div id="lightboxMainContent">
<fieldset class="referral_lightbox">
<label class="inputLabel" for="referral_dropdown">How did you hear about us?</label>
<select id="referral_dropdown" name="referral_dropdown">
        <option>Newspaper</option>
        <option>Google</option>
        <option>Friend</option>
</select>
</fieldset>
<fieldset class="referral_friend" style="display:none;">
<label class="inputLabel" for="referral_friend_dropdown">Referral:</label>
<?php
$referralFriendArray = zen_get_referral_info();
//$referralFriendArray = array("First Friend", "Second Friend", "Third Friend"); ?>

<select id="referral_friend_dropdown" name="referral_friend_dropdown">
<?php foreach($referralFriendArray as $row => $value){

        echo '<option value="'.$row.'">' . $value . '</option>';

} ?>

</select>
<br class="clearBoth" />
</fieldset>
</div>
<div class="lightboxButtons">
<input type="button" name="lightboxSkip" id="lightboxSkip" value="Skip" style="width:100px;">
<input type="button" name="lightboxContinue" id="lightboxContinue" value="Continue" style="width:100px;">
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: Any errors? And do you perhaps have some more code? HTML? That could be easier to spot your problem.

Comment: Added my html....if I remove the `.submit();` from my jquery code the lightbox appears.